# math.random() not working when array declared in javascript

Tags: javascript, arrays, random

I was trying to create a function to select random number on click event for a button. But it seems function doesn't work (although there is no error shown) when i declare an array and/OR use array.length to multiply to Math.random. Without declaring array or using its length, function seems to be working fine. here is the code:

```
const quoteArea = document.querySelector(".quote");
const randomButton = document.getElementById("btn__random");
const quoteArr = [a , b, c];
randomButton.addEventListener("click", randomizeQuote);

function randomizeQuote() {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(quoteArr.length * Math.random());

  quoteArea.innerHTML = randomNum;
}
```

Comment: `a`, `b`, and `c` are not defined. So `const quoteArr = [a , b, c]` isn't valid.

Comment: Try using the code snippet button to create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). I bet you'll get an accurate answer quicker! (Assuming you just shortened your `quoteArr` declaration and something else is the real issue)

Comment: @JKillian this is my first question. still figuring out how everything works

Comment: @SpencerWieczorek thanks. found out the issue.

Answer (score 0):

```js
const quoteArea = document.querySelector(".quote");
const randomButton = document.getElementById("btn__random");
const quoteArr = ['a' , 'b', 'c'];
randomButton.addEventListener("click", randomizeQuote);

function randomizeQuote() {
  const randomNum = Math.floor(quoteArr.length * Math.random());

  quoteArea.innerHTML = randomNum;
}
```

```html
<button id='btn__random'>Random</button>
<p class='quote'></p>
```

You did not defined your `quoteArr` array properly where a,b,c are undefined, Changed to `quoteArr = ['a' , 'b', 'c'];`